# Windows Server 2008 and com objects

Tags: com, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I'm moving a Dll (built in c++) from windows 2000 server to a 2008 server but im have some trouble registering it. In 2000 all you normaly have to do is a "regsrv32 name.dll" but this will not work in 2008 because you get a pointer error, iv also tried to use "gacutil /i name.dll" because someone told me this might work, but it didnt. So, I'm kind of desperate, is there anyone that have some solution to how i can get this c++ dll to work in 2000 server so that i can access it from an old classic asp page.

EDIT:
This is the error when running regsrv:
"
The module "name.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Make sure that "name.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.
"

Note that I cant edit the dll file in anyway.

Comment: Citing the exact text of the error message from regsvr32 might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If UAC is enabled, are you running an elevated command prompt when you call regsvr32? If not, you'll probably get an access denied error in the registration function (which could manifest itself in all sorts of bad ways for something that old).

You have to be logged in as an admin, then run Command Prompt with right-click, "Run as administrator".

Comment: I am running as true administrator.

Comment: But are you running the command prompt elevated? Vista, 2008, and Win7 have yet another layer of security- you have to "assert" your privilege when you start a process, or you get a "weak sauce" version of administrator that can't really do anything.

Comment: Ah nevermind- your error message proves that it's not a normal COM server. If DllRegisterServer isn't there, self-reg with regsvr32 won't work.